# Postgres function return Records issue

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am creating a function which creates well, but when I call it there is issue.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.winner_pagination(
    _searchText varchar,
    _sort varchar, _order char(3), _limit int, _offset int)
  RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

BEGIN

RETURN QUERY SELECT CREATED_DATE as createddate, DELETED AS deleted, FIRST_NAME AS firstname, LAST_NAME AS lastname,
 NO_OF_AWARDS AS noofawards, PHONE AS phone, COUNTRY_ID AS country, ORGId_ID AS orgId , EMAIL as email
 FROM winner 
 WHERE deleted = false
 and ORGId_ID = 1
 and first_name LIKE _searchText OR last_name LIKE _searchText  OR email LIKE _searchText   OR phone LIKE _searchText 
 order by _sort  limit _limit offset _offset;

END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.winner_pagination(varchar, varchar, char(3), int, int)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I am calling the function like this

```
 select * from winner_pagination('Arthur', 'firstname', 'asc', 9, 0)
  as f(createddate date, deleted boolean, firstname varchar, lastname varchar,  noofawards integer ,
   phone varchar,  country integer,  orgId integer,  email varchar ) ;

ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
SQL state: 42804
Detail: Returned type timestamp without time zone does not match expected type date in column 1.
Context: PL/pgSQL function winner_pagination(character varying,character varying,character,integer,integer) line 6 at RETURN QUERY
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you cannot cast implicitly in the alias. You must use the exact types of the function result (which uses the exact types of the `RETURN QUERY`'s query). -- If your method returns a fix format, you can use `OUT` parameters or the `RETURNS TABLE(...)` format to indicate column names and types. That way, you don't have to specify aliases when calling the function.

Comment: You should also write your conditions carefully  with `and` and `or`. so seems better: `deleted = false
 and ORGId_ID = 1
 and (first_name LIKE _searchText OR last_name LIKE _searchText  OR email LIKE _searchText   OR phone LIKE _searchText)`

Comment: why not `... returns table (createddate date, deleted boolean, firstname varchar, lastname varchar,  noofawards integer ,
   phone varchar,  country integer,  orgId integer,  email varchar )` ?..